# How to sum values of the same row from different columns in a separate sheet with QUERY?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to add up the value of cells in the same row but different columns to another Google sheet.

Example below:

[image]

Comment: **pls share a copy of your sheet and add more info what exactly you need**

Comment: **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers**

Answer (score -1):

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A3:O}; "select Col2+Col5+Col8+Col11 label Col2+Col5+Col8+Col11''"; 0)
```

[image: 0]